# The marker image not displayed in map

Tags: android, google-maps

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    BitmapDescriptor markLocation = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.abc);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(markLocation);
    markerOptions.draggable(true);
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));
}
```

The image is saved in drawable folder but image is not displayed when the current location in `map`.

Comment: your drawable is XML or Vector drawable ?

Comment: I'm sorry how to find it is vector drawable or xml?

Comment: you added the drawable is "abc", what is it?is it PNG file or custom drawable ?

Comment: .png file sir..

Comment: i post the answer have look.

Answer (score 0):

Hi As per my Understanding, You can display Marker like this format

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude)))     // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
            .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude)))
            .title(location_name)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.big_marker)));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use `InvokeIcon()` for showing marker icon on map, have look:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    BitmapDescriptor markLocation = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.abc);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.draggable(true);
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    markerOptions.InvokeIcon(markLocation);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to load Marker-:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude)))
            .title("India")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
```